# Javafx fxml file with errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I'm opening new JavaFX project in IntelliJ, I have all necessary files of JDK installed, but in fxml file there are multiple errors "Unexpected token". This error shows immediately after opening new javafx project and fxml file (meaning there's nothing I add or remove from the basic fxml tags). What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow IntelliJ [instructions here](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html).

1. Download and install JDK 7 or a later version (earlier JDK versions don't include the JavaFX SDK necessary for JavaFX application development).
2. If you are going to use JavaFX Scene Builder, download and install it as well.
3. Make sure that the JavaFX plugin is enabled. (JavaFX support in IntelliJ IDEA in based on the JavaFX plugin. This plugin is bundled with the IDE and enabled by default.) See To make sure that the JavaFX plugin is enabled.
4. Define the JDK in IntelliJ IDEA. You can do that separately (see To define JDK 7 in IntelliJ IDEA) or when creating a project or module (see Creating a project for JavaFX development).
5. If necessary, specify the path to the JavaFX Scene Builder executable file. If you do so, you'll be able to open your FXML files in the Scene Builder right in IntelliJ IDEA. See To specify the path to the JavaFX Scene Builder executable file.
6. Create a project for your JavaFX application development. Your can create the corresponding project from scratch or, if you already have the source files you want to continue working with, you can create a project by importing the corresponding sources. See Creating a project for JavaFX development or Creating a Project by Importing Existing Sources. See also, Using Scene Builder with IntelliJ IDEA.